# Sending HTML Newsletter with SendGrid Bronze Plan

Tags: sendgrid

In an effort to cut cost, my boss would like me to use SendGrid bronze plan to send HTML newsletter to our customers. (We are using EmailBrain currently.)

However, the bronze plan doesn't seem to provide the newsletter app available in the silver and above plans.

Thus, I would like to ask:

- Is it possible to send out bulk email blast (HTML newsletter with an unsubscribe link) without using the newsletter app?
- If possible, is it difficult to set such things up manually or any tips for doing so?
- Are there any good alternatives with a similar or lower price point (but having a newsletter app component?

It seems my boss is mainly concerned about the cost and not so much about other stuff. Our total emails is around 28,500+ (user base growing at a very slow pace) blasting to about 0 to 3 times a month.